# Simpler way to show individual sequantial numbers with JQuery

Tags: jquery, setinterval

Every second I want to show a number until the total is reached. Here's the working code for 10 numbers. As you can see I typed each number individually from 1 to 10. Now what if I want to do this for 5,000 numbers? Surely there must be an easier way to put a list of sequential numbers in the "numbers" variable.

```js
(function() {
  var timesRun = 0;
  var numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    i = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    timesRun += 1;
    if (timesRun < 10) {
      $('#changing-number').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).html(numbers[i = (i + 1) % numbers.length]).fadeIn();
      });
    }
  }, 1000);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="changing-number">0</span> out of 10 have been completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just show `timesRun`, since it's a sequential number.

You should also clear the interval when you reach the limit.

You should also increment the counter *after* you check it against the limit, otherwise you won't show the last value.

```js
(function() {
  var timesRun = 0;
  var runLimit = 10;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (timesRun < runLimit) {
      timesRun += 1;
      $('#changing-number').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).html(timesRun).fadeIn();
      });
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="changing-number">0</span> out of 10 have been completed
```

If you want to do more numbers, change `runLimit`.